# Flutter how to set white primarySwatch color for ThemeData?

Tags: flutter

When I try to set white primarySwatch color, I got error: `type 'Color' is not a subtype of type 'MaterialColor'`. How to solve this?

Comment: The referenced duplicates do not answer this question directly. I had to delete the `primarySwatch` parameter and a use `primaryColor: Colors.white` instead

Comment: Use `Colors.grey`.
The confusion I believe is due to poor naming decision:
`Colors.red` is a `MaterialColor`, while `Colors.white` or `Colors.black` are simple Color objects. So `primaryColor: Colors.red` is correct while `primaryColor:Colors.white` is not.